# Constructor initializer list doesn't follow order

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

I have following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int test) { std::cout << "Base constructor, test: " << test << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int variable;

public:
    Derived() :
        variable(50),
        Base(variable)
    {}
};

Derived derived;
```

And I would expect that output would be: "Base constructor, test: 50", but that isn't the case, because `Base` constructor gets called before `variable` is initialized, there is no error nor warning, it just compiles.

Is there any way i can make `Base` constructor get called after ? Or is this generally bad design ?

I'm tryting to get rid of all the init methods and their calls by putting them into constructor insted, this behavior stop me from doing that.

Comment: Activate warning, `: variable(50), Base(variable)` is a wrong order.

Comment: [base-from-member-idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member).

Comment: Shame this was closed: I was writing an answer for you suggesting to use `Derived() : Base(variable = 50) {} ` for your derived c'tor.

Comment: Shame this was closed: The question closing invalidated my answer - look into **delegating constructors** if you ever need a value to be produced **before** any constructors are called.

Comment: @AdrianMole - given that there were two answers in the queue, I am reopening.  Please add your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way i can make Base constructor get called after?

No.  An object's constructor must construct its base classes before any named member variables.

> I'm trying to get rid of all the init methods and their calls by putting them into constructor instead

That is a worthwhile effort!

I'll assume your *real code* `variable` is something more complex than an `int`.  Because if it's an int, you could simply call `Base(50)`.

You can use [**delagating constructors**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor) to prepare a variable before any constructor begins initialization.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // Generate an important value FIRST, and then delegate
    // construction to a new constructor.
    Derived() : Derived( GenerateSomethingComplex() ) {}

private:

    // Here, we can honor constructing Base before Derived
    // while "some value" has been procured in advance.
    Derived( SomethingComplex&& var) :
        Base( var ),
        variable( std::move(var) )
    {}

    SomethingComplex variable;

};
```